# OpenVPN 'client' is not running

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have tried a set of various commands to start the openvpn client including(on ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo update-rc.d openvpn defaults
sudo service openvpn start
/etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

I get the following output :-

```
 * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...                                                                                                                           
  *   Autostarting VPN 'client'
```

But when I verify the status, I get the following output:-

```
root@ingtech:/etc/openvpn# **sudo service openvpn status
 * VPN 'client' is not running**
```

I know for the fact that I cant use systemctl, as I am on ubuntu 14.04.
Please help me get the vpnclient up and running. Rest assured that VPN client config file is correct.

Comment: This is how the hide-me setup shows it starting for 14.04....{sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/MyFile.ovpn}. I'm not sure you can access there setup page without registering but  here's the link...https://hide.me/en/vpnsetup/ubuntu-legacy/openvpn/